# How to start a spring boot tomcat server on a specified port through command prompt

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, microservices

I have a very simple "Hello World" kind of REST api created using Spring Boot that is accessible through http://localhost:8080/greeting/world without any problem.

I would like to start two more instances of this API on ports 8081 and 8082 but not able to do so. It says `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`

**Command Used:**

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=8081
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: world-greeting-service
```

**WorldGreetingServiceApplication.java**

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class WorldGreetingServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WorldGreetingServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/greeting/world")
    public String greetWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you checked that the ports 8080, 8081, 8082 are not already in used ? Can you give us a complete error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using,

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8081'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar world-greeting-service.jar --server.port=8081
```

This command is an equivalent of above answer and can be used when you don't have `maven` installed